# How to lock and reload an entity correctly

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee

In my web application I have several threads that potentially access the same data concurrently why I decided to implement optimistic (versioning) and pessimistic locking with Hibernate.

Currently I use the following pattern to lock an entity and perform write operations on it (using Springs Transaction manager and transaction demarcation with @Transactional):

```
@Transactional
public void doSomething(entity) {
    session.lock(entity, LockMode.UPGRADE);
    session.refresh(entity);

    // I change the entity itself as well as entites in a relationship.
    entity.setBar(...);
    for(Child childEntity : entity.getChildren()) {
        childEntity.setFoo(...);
    }
}
```

However, sometimes I am getting `StaleObjectException` when the @Transactional is flushing that tells me that a ChildEntity has been modifed concurrently and now has a wrong version.

I guess I am **not correctly refreshing `entity` and its children** so I am working with stale data. Can someone point out how to achieve this? Some thoughts of me included clearing the persistence context (the session) or calling `session.lock(entity, LockMode.READ)` again, but I am not sure what is correct here.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take at look at this Hibernate-Issue: [LockMode.Upgrade doesn't refresh entity values](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HB-1403).

In short: Hibernat does NOT perform a select after a successful lock if the given entity was already preloaded. You need to call refresh for the entity for yourself after you received the lock.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you make "LockMode.UPGRADE" and optimistic locking live together? Seem like controversial things.

Hibernate never lock objects in memory and always use the locking mechanism of the database. Also, "if the requested lock mode is not supported by the database, Hibernate uses an appropriate alternate mode instead of throwing an exception. This ensures that applications are portable.". It means, that if your database doesn't support SELECT ... FOR UPDATE, most probably, you will get these exceptions.

Another possible reason is that you haven't used "org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK" for children.

Comment: I am using MySQL InnoDB which supports "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE", so I don't see a problem here. Furthermore, I am usimg optimistic locking too, in order to get a "notification" when a concurrent modification was made.

Comment: Sorry, missed the point that you have problem with children (which is in bold :)). I have updated answer...

Comment: In my code I always lock on entity, even if I only want to update the entity not the children. So there should also be the lock acquired. My main concern actuall is that I am not working with the newest entity/children by only using refresh.

Comment: I'm confused, sorry. I believed that you are working with latest version of entity, but there is problem with children. I believe that the problem arise because children as not locked (org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK) is not defined for them. Is is the case or I'm missing something? If you do not lock children, there is no guarantee that you are working with the latest version of them. On the other hand, the main entity has to be the latest one, because you explicitly lock it before call to refresh()